# Lazy loading of Doctrine one-to-one associations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've been reading a lot about Doctrine lately and I have seen a general suggestion to avoid bi-directional One-To-One associations. [This page](https://tideways.io/profiler/blog/5-doctrine-orm-performance-traps-you-should-avoid) (from June 2015) states:

```
... you should avoid bidirectional one-to-one associations in Doctrine. 
    The inverse side of a one-to-one association cannot be lazy loaded.
```

I am assuming that *cannot be lazy loaded* means something like *must be eager-loaded* .

The page is also called "Doctrine Performance Traps", so it looks scary :)

Since the [manual on one-to-one](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional) doesn't mention this, I have decided to test and see for myself. I found a couple of classes in our test app that were already using one-to-one associations, so this was easy:

```
class Recipe
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Image")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="image_id", unique=true, referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $image;
}

class Image
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Recipe")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="recipe_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $recipe;
}
```

Next, I try to select an image in my controller:

```
$image = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Image')->find(658);
```

In Symfony profiler I see one sql query with no joins. In the dumped image data, under Recipe, I see:

```
+__isInitialized__: false
```

Which would mean that the Recipe entity was lazy-loaded?

The same happens when I load the Recipe: Image gets lazy-loaded.

Adding `inversedBy` to any of the entities doesn't seem to make a difference.

It seems that either the article I was reading was incorrect, or something has changed in Doctrine since then, or I don't understand lazy-loading.

Questions:

- Can latest versions of doctrine lazy-load bidirectional one-to-ones?
- Why are bidirectional one-to-one associations so frequently considered harmful for performance?

I understand that a lot of times I can get away without using bidirectional mapping, but sometimes I really really need to have them and I am just trying to understand the price of this decision.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making some confusion between lazy and eager loading.

The **Lazy Loading** does not load the related data with the join statement: when you try to access to the child object (from the parent) you actually make a call to a proxy object that will trigger a select statement with the proper conditions. Lazy loading should be avoided when you want to fetch data that will be accessed for sure.

The **Eager Loading** loads the related data with a join statement in a single query. This will help you solving the "n+1" overhead.

Let's assume you have some categories and subcategories splitted in one table (I know, this is weird for a database normalization approach but will help us get the score): you are going to display a menu with the categories AND the subcategories. With the Eager Loading, for each category you will make a select statement for getting the subcategory data (i.e. the name you will display on your menu).

For what regards the bidirectional one-to-one relationship, the reason why loading it bidirectionally cause an overhead is pretty simple: let's assume that A has a one-to-one with B. When you load A you are gonna make a proxy object that points straight to B. If you set a bidirectional relationship, your proxy object B will contain an (unuseful) A proxy object too.

Hope this helps (and that I didn't make any mistake actually) (:

Comment: I understood the phrase  **The inverse side of a one-to-one association cannot be lazy loaded** in a way that **It must be eager-loaded because it can't be lazy loaded** :) That's why I was expecting a join.

Answer (score 1):

Your mapping for a bidirectional one-to-one association is not correct. Usually you have the `@JoinColumn` only on one end of the association, not on both ends:

```
<?php
class Recipe
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Image", mappedBy="recipe")
     */
    private $image;
}

class Image
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Recipe", inversedBy="image")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="recipe_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $recipe;
}
```

See http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional

If you set up your mapping like this and load the `Recipe` you will see the expected `JOIN` with the `Image` table.